# Ctrl + A does not work in Chrome Address bar

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I just bought Dell Laptop with Windows 10 Pro.

Everything looks ok except for the Ctrl + A  in Chrome Address bar.

When I press Ctrl + A I get beep sound and nothing happens.

I can Ctrl + C & Ctrl + V & Ctrl + X, but Ctrl + A is a problem

Has anyone faced such problem before or know how to fix that?

Comment: Where are you trying to use that shortcut?

Comment: in Chrome Address bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the cause

it was instant multilingual translator extension installed in chrome.

removed and fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem and it appeared that a Kiosk extension was the cause.